How do Calvinists defend against the incident of the two thieves on the cross regarding predestination?
I believe God did not coerce the thief to the right to confess that Jesus is the Messiah, he did it because he loved the truth and out of his free will, the thief to the left also did not mock Jesus because the devil incited him but most probably because he wanted to appease the crowd. The actions of these two thieves , one in repentance and the other in rebellion caused them to go to different places in the afterlife. How do Calvinists who say God has already chosen the elect and our free will doesn't matter defend this?
Also if God interferes with your free will to achieve a result where you go to heaven, then the race of salvation is not fair, or if He interferes with your free will to make you go to hell, makes him a crucial factor in your condemnation, which is not the case .

Without addressing if your understanding of Calvinism is correct, isn't your first sentence simply begging the question? If we assume that Calvinism is wrong, then Calvinism is wrong. But a Calvinist obviously rejects that assumption, there's nothing to explain.

A Calvinist (such as myself) would also object to the OP's characterization of Calvinistic election as coercive.

Calvinists are compatibilists: they believe that while God is sovereign and he determines everything about the universe, humans make genuine and real choices, and when they sin it is because they want to and choose to sin, and God is not the cause of or responsible for their sin.
While there are nuances to the Reformed position (such as the debate between supralapsarianism and infralapsarianism), ultimately compatibilism between divine and human wills is one of the great Mysteries of the Christian faith. It is beyond the capacity of a human to understand in full how God relates to the creation. We are not asked to resolve the unresolvable to our own satisfaction, but to accept and trust what God in his scriptures clearly teaches us: that he is in charge, and we are responsible for our choices.

Well explained , it is true that we are not in a position to understand the interaction of God with his creation, upvoted for the comment that people choose and God isn't responsible for their errors.

There is nothing to defend, for some misunderstanding is evidenced here, e.g. The "thief to the left also did not mock Jesus because the devil incited him but most probably because he wanted to appease the crowd."
There was mockery, a bit earlier on. Matthew 27:38-44 needs to be studied, especially after the chief priests, scribes and elders mocked Christ on the cross, then we are told:

"The thieves also, which were crucified with him, cast the same
[mockery] in his teeth." Matthew 27:44 A.V. & Mark 16:27-33

Ah, but that was before supernatural darkness began at noon. No eclipse, there, for it lasted for three hours. That likely affected the thieves (plural) but in opposite ways. The malefactor on the right rebuked the other one, who had mockingly said,

"If thou be Christ, save thyself and us." But the other answering
rebuked him, saying, "Dost thou not fear God, seeing thou art in the
same condemnation? And we indeed justly; for we receive the due reward
for our deeds: but this man hath done nothing amiss." Luke 23:32-41
A.V.

The question presents the claim that "the devil" incited the thief who did not repent. Either that, or this dying man "wanted to appease the crowd". What? Even if that thief could appease the crowd, that would not help him now! And he certainly could not do anything. Only if he repented, before Jesus' gave up his spirit to God, could his outcome change from cruel hopelessness to "Christ in you, the hope of glory" (Colossians 1:27). Yet the other thief clearly did repent of his earlier mockery, and expressed his faith in the resurrection of Jesus, asking for Christ to remember him, when Christ came into his kingdom. And Jesus said yes, he would. That is in Luke 23:42-43.
As for, "The actions of these two thieves, one in repentance and the other in rebellion caused them to go to different places in the afterlife." Well, neither could do anything. The one and only option, open equally to both of them, was to repent and put their faith in Jesus. One did. The other did not. But that was not unique to them. That is exactly the same option before every single person. They will not be forced to take either one option, or the other. The fact that God knows, from before creation, which of his creatures will turn to him, in faith, and those who will not, is only an aggravation to those who either don't believe God exists (which is ridiculous, given they have ruled God out of the equation from the start), or those who think God can only do so much to "offer" salvation, but that it is up to them "to conclude the deal". Such thinking betrays grave misunderstanding of what God did, in Christ, on the cross. But that is not the question here, so I end my answer with:
There is nothing to defend, for the matter in question is not a problem for 'Calvinists'.

My point is that the foreknowledge of God doesn't interfere with the choice you have been provided with, he did not interfere with the choice Adam and Eve made. He left them to make their own choice which ultimately decided their fate. I do believe God knows the events on obedience and on repentance , it's as simple as that but the choice is yours. The choice was Adam and Eve's. Your presented with a choice and God watchs from a distance. If your choice didn't matter then God wouldn't let you make one.

So that through your own choice , God is innocent of your choices and everybody else, you only have yourself to blame. I alone made the wrong choice , the devil didn't coerce me, neither did men or angels or God, it is I who reasoned in my heart and rejected God.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany  Glad to hear it, knowing from your profile page that you then turned to God in faith and believe his word, the Bible

Every individual was provided with a mind and a heart for this very purpose. You do all the reasoning with the two and finally make a choice that has a bearing on your eternal destiny. You have to make a choice , human beings are being held accountable because they are in control of their own actions and are aware of the consequences. If He presented angels with a choice , he presented the devil with a choice to keep his former place or start a revolt, he chose the later, and that sealed his destiny.

mystical beings were sent to spy on me during my high school years. A prophet exposed them and confirmed what my own conscience was concluding from logic, that it is impossible to be in New York and know what your classmate is doing in his or her own house in Michigan without the intervention of malicious supernatural beings. Spirits of people who didn't die in Christ were the ones being sent. The prophet told me.

@Anne   Very clear. Very precise. Very compelling. Up-voted +1.
